# Excel copy a snippet cell A to cell B

Tags: excel, copy, spreadsheet

This might be an easy one but in cell A2 I got a value of  "123-123 Example Text" how can I make it copy only "123-123" and put the value in cell A3.

Second part in B2 I have "123-123"  and in  B3 I got "www.website.com/image/X.jpg" is there a way to tell it to take B2 and insert it instead of X in B3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in A3 add the formula

```
 =LEFT(A2,7)
```

in B3 you would need to put

```
="www.website.com/image/"&B2&".jpg"
```

**Note:**
If in the first part if the value 123-123 could be longer or shorter you would need to find the first space and then cut it to there using a formula like so

```
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)
```